# How can I move the current input down in Python?

Tags: python, input, text, ansi-escape

I'm making a simple webserver with Python, and I want to be able to run commands while the displaying requests that the server is getting. Normally, this would happen:

```
Request from 127.0.0.1 - GET /index.html
Request from 127.0.0.1 - GET /login.html
Input command: asRequest from 127.0.0.1 - GET /login.htmldf
```

(in this example, I typed `as`, then the request came in, then I finished by typing `df`)

I want to move the prompt down a line, so I can keep the scrollback buffer, while keeping what was already typed in. I know this is possible, since (for example) in Minecraft server console, this is done:

[image: example]

(I started typing before)

and the prompt, text, and cursor is moved down. I tried using ANSI escape codes to achieve the effect, but it doesn't seem to work:

```py
import threading
from time import sleep

def print_req():
    sleep(3)
    # \033[_D moves the cursor _ columns to the left, 1000 just means it will be on the far left 
    print("\033[1000D\r\n") # \r\n to (try to) move everything down a line

t = threading.Thread(target=print_req)
t.start()

print("Request from 127.0.0.1 - GET /index.html")
input("> ") # to test, type something in the 3 seconds
```

This happens:

[image: the cursor just moves down without moving text]

As you can see, the cursor just moves down 2 lines without moving the text.

I already asked a similar question to this on here, but it got set as a duplicate of another, different question and wasn't answered. Any help would be greatly appreciated, TIA!

Answer (score 1):

This is because Inputs don’t have multiline like kivy or anything python terminal inputs don’t really
Have this function